# Was there any civilisation in the world which evolved without the concept of god?

Tags: gods, universe

Was there any civilisation in the world which evolved without the concept of god? Apparently the Piraha people have no concept of numbers, time, or a supreme being.

Comment: Yoga Vasistha says there are worlds where there are no Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra.

Comment: Should it be moved to mythology.SE ?